# ListAdapter blink on refresh

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

After setting up a ListAdapter I get this weird behavior with my widget that flicker each update, i tried to disable recyclerview animation but it did nothing. Someone have an idea?

[Weird blinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpox2.gif)

Edit:

Here's is my callback

```
class DlDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Data>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Data, newItem: Data): Boolean {
        return oldItem.progress === newItem.progress
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Data, newItem: Data): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `ListAdapter`, I assume you implemented `ItemCallback` as well? My guess would be that `areItemsTheSame()` returns `false` for items that do are the same.

Comment: Yes I implemented ItemCallback and it return oldItem === newItem but maybe it's link to this return, I added it to my post

Comment: Don't use `===`. Use `==`. `areItemsTheSame` is supposed to return whether the old and new data represent the same item, not whether they have the same instance. You should be comparing something like a unique ID, not a `progress` value. Also, make sure you are not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. When using ListAdapter, you should only use `submitList()` without any of the "notify" functions.

Comment: The reason it's blinking is because the item (maybe the whole list?) is being cleared and recreated, which is animated with a fade when items are removed and added. You want the adapter to see that it's *the same item* (and just update what's currently displayed on it)  - that's what @Tenfour04 is talking about

Comment: you should do oldItem.id == newItem.id and not oldItem == newItem